# How to handle multiple TCP clients for communication

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, tcp, tcplistener

I'm developing multi client `TCP/IP` server application that may receive some commands from different clients and on the basis of these commands the server would perform some actions and send back the response to client accordingly.

My question is how to handle multiple clients to send the relevant data back to that particular client after processing. How to pass the reference of `TCP client` when sending data to server and how to preserve it so that the response can be sent back to its relevant `TCPClient`.

I'm using `TCPlistner` for creating `TCPClient` object. That is `oTCPClient = oTCPListener.AcceptTcpClient();`. So how to create relevant `NetworkStream` for each `TCPClient` for communication.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `ConnectedClient` class which takes a `TCPClient` in the constructor, then start a thread in that object which reads the `NetworkStream` of the `TCPClient` for incoming data.
You could also have a method in `ConnectedClient` for sending data. Whenever you receive data and want to reply to or forward the message, you can call `SendData` on one or more of the stored `ConnectedClient` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of a server that can handle multiple clients and respond to multiple clients

```
class MultyClientServer
{
    private static int bufferSize = 2048;
    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
    private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Server";
        SetupServer();
        Console.ReadKey();
        CloseAllSockets();
    }

    private static void SetupServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Settings Up Server Plz Wait");
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, YOUR PORT HERE));
        serverSocket.Listen(10);
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(CallBack), null);
        Console.WriteLine("Server Made");
    }

    private static void CallBack(IAsyncResult e)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(e);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(CallBack), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult e)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)e.AsyncState;
            int received;
            try
            {
                received = socket.EndReceive(e);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                socket.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(socket);
                return;
            }
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, dataBuf, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Client request: " + text);

            string response = string.Empty;


            try
            {
                if (command.ToLower() == "What Time is it")
                {
                    response = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                }
                else if (command.ToLower() == "Whats your name")
                {
                    response = "Tyler Gregorcyk";
                }
                else
                {
                    response = "Invaled";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception et) { Console.WriteLine(et.Message); socket.Close(); clientSockets.Remove(socket); }


            if(response == string.Empty)
            {
                response = "Invaled";
            }

            if (response != string.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sent To Client: " + response);
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                socket.Send(data);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(CallBack), null);
            }

            conn.Close();
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallBack, socket);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private static void CloseAllSockets()
    {
        foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }

        serverSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

BTW this is a edited version of a tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI